# could not find component on update server. contact vmware support or your system administrator mac os

Tags: mac, vmware-workstation

I am getting this while mac os is loading and it will be loading itself

could not find component on update server. contact vmware support or your system administrator mac os

VMware details:

VMware workstation 8

trying to install mac Os 10.8

currently using Os windows8